# angular - cannot show/hide directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I seem not to be able to show or hide `ng-incude` directives

css:

```
#header, #mainarea {
    display:none;
}
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id='login'></div>
    <div id='header' ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
    <div id='mainarea' ng-include="'views/mainarea.html'"></div>
<body>
```

js(myCtrl):

```
$scope.login = $('#login');
$scope.header = $('#header');
$scope.main = $('#mainarea');

if (correctUser) {
    $scope.header.show();
    $scope.main.show();
} else {
    $scope.login.hide();
}
```

I have even included jQuery link before angular, but for some strange reason I cannot display the ng-include directives :(

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky problem here, and it's due to the fact that you will not be able to work with jQuery the way you are used to do it.

When controller is executed HTML for `#header` div really looks like this:

```
<!-- ngInclude: 'views/header.html' -->
```

because `ngInclude` takes it out of the DOM and appends when it's necessary (when template is loaded and ready to be displayed). As the result when you try to set up a reference to this element with jQuery like this

```
$scope.header = $('#header');
```

it doesn't find anything, because there is no such id in DOM yet.

So this is a good example why you should not work in jQuery-like style in Angular app. Instead, you should use ngShow/ngHide/ngIf directives:

```
<div ng-if="correctUser" ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

where `correctUser` comes from controller:

```
$scope.correctUser = true;
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/E0uwbcsmishmRO2HROnm?p=preview

Comment: Let say I want to apply an animation like fadeIn or any other animations. So that when the button is clicked the $scope.header = true; $scope.main =true will be nicely faded in. Is this possible please?

Comment: also ng-click doesn't seem to apply  `$scope.correctUser = true` on trigger unless I reload the page after I clicked the button :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ng-if, without jquery and CSS display:none.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div id='login' ng-if="login"></div>
   <div id='header' ng-if="header" ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
   <div id='mainarea' ng-if="main" ng-include="'views/mainarea.html'"></div>
<body>
```

and in your ctrl

```
$scope.login = true;
$scope.header = false;
$scope.main = false;

if(correctUser){
   $scope.header = true;
   $scope.main = true;
}else{
   $scope.login = false;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but let say I want to apply an animation like fadeIn or any other animations. So that when the button is clicked the `$scope.header = true; $scope.main =true` will be nicely faded in. Is this possible please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/cuv7f92x/) based on your code.

My strong suggestion is dont mix and match jquery and angularjs. Try previous answers and try to stick purely with angularjs.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.correctUser = false;
    $scope.lookfor = function(){
        $scope.correctUser = !$scope.correctUser;
if($scope.correctUser){
$('#header').show();
$('#mainarea').show();
}else{
$('#header').hide();
$('#mainarea').hide();
}
    }

})
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="lookfor()">Show Header</button>

  <div id='header'>Header Template</div>
 <div id='mainarea'>Main Area Template</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #header, #mainarea{
display:none;
}
```